# What experiment could be done to test if curved 4D space-time is embedded in flat 5D spacetime?

Tags: general-relativity

Obviously it is not needed to embed any solution of Einstein's equations in a higher dimensional flat space, although it can be done.

If we had a theory that space-time was a curved 4D manifold in a flat 5D spacetime, how would we test this theory?

This would imply, I believe: $g_{\mu\nu}(x) \equiv \partial_\mu X^N(x) \partial_\nu X^N(x)$ for N=1..5.

What effects could we test for? Are there some solutions of Einsteins equations that could only be embedded in 6D and hence the prediction would be these can't exist?

What other effects might we observe?

Comment: The [Whitney embedding theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_embedding_theorem) and its extensions say that not every compact orientable 4-D manifold can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^5$;  for at least some 4D manifolds, $\mathbb{R}^7$ is required.  But (a) spacetime is not usually assumed to be compact, and (b) this is a topological property of manifolds, and requiring that the 4-D metric is induced by the embedding would introduce additional constraints.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert: I think it's even worse for non-compact manifolds, isn't it?

Comment: @tfb:  I'm not sure about non-compact manifolds;  any further references would be most appreciated.

Comment: Also, note that once you have a smooth embedding of the manifold into $\mathbb{R}^N$ for which the distances between points are not increased (i.e., a [nonexpanding map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_map), the [Nash embedding theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nash_embedding_theorem) guarantees the existence of a map that's arbitrarily close to isometric.  So the metric condition isn't as big of an impediment as I originally thought.

Comment: Also you only need to consider Einsteinian Manifolds. But apart from that interlude, i was really interested about physical experiments.